# How to define conditions under which linear maps are injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, vectors

In this book (http://linear.axler.net/) proposition 3.2 states the following:

**Proposition 3.2**: A linear map $T : V \rightarrow W$ from vector space $V$ to vector space $W$ is injective if and only if $null(T) = \{0\}$, meaning the null space of $T$ consists only of the $0$ vector.

I'm confused about the proof of this. The proof in book relies a fact that stated earlier that says that if $T$ is a linear map, then by the property of *additivity* one can show that:

$T(0) = T(0 + 0) = T(0) + T(0)$

which makes sense, but the book then says "which implies that $T(0) = 0$. Thus $0 \in null(T)$." This part does not make sense to me. How could $T(0) = 0$ be guaranteed for all linear maps? What if the linear map is the function $T(x) = x + 1$, which maps a vector to a vector with the elements plus one. Then clearly $T(0) \neq 0$, and so I don't see how the argument carries.

Comment: Subtract $T(0)$ from both sides of $T(0)=T(0)+T(0)$. Also, $T(x)=x+1$ is not a linear map.

Comment: $T(x) = x+1$ is not linear in the sense of linear algebra. For linear $T$, you have $$\begin{align}0 = T(0) - T(0) &= T(0+0) - T(0) = \bigl(T(0)+T(0)\bigr) - T(0)\\ &= T(0) + \bigl(T(0) - T(0)\bigr) = T(0) + 0 = T(0).\end{align}$$

Comment: So linear map and linear function are not interchangeable?

Comment: Maps like $T(x)= x + 1$ are sometimes called *affine linear* maps. They include the functions you normally think of as generating lines in the plane. If the line doesn't pass through the origin, you have such an affine linear map that is not linear (in the linear algebraic sense).

Comment: What is a linear map intuitively then (e.g. in 2d space) if not a linear function? It seems like an odd concept

Comment: It's more that the term *linear* has different meanings in different contexts.  In regular calculus, a linear map/function is one that has the form $f(x)=mx+b$.  In linear algebra, a linear map/function has the property that $$f(\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2)=\lambda_1 f(x_1)+ \lambda_2 f(x_2).$$

Comment: @Unwisdom: linear algebra describes solutions to linear equations though and in case of two equations, the solutions are where the two *lines* intersect, so the equations are definitively of form $f(x) = mx + b$. can you explain the connection between linear maps and this? Why bother with the special case of linear maps as opposed to linear functions? I think I am missing the relevance of linear maps